# After update to Visual Studio 2019 on Mac, integration with Azure DevOps TFS server broken

Tags: tfs, azure-devops, visual-studio-mac

After my recent upgrade to Visual Studio 2019 (?) on Mac, I am unable to connect to my TFS server using the TFS Source Control extension.

My current setup:

> Visual Studio for Mac, version 8.0.3.14

Source Control Extension:

> Team Foundation Version Control for TFS and Azure DevOps Version
>   0.4.4.5

Steps: In Team Explorer, now I see two options:
1) Add Account 
2) Add Server

When I try Add Account, a dialog pops up asking for my MS credentials - I enter them as usual, and then nothing further happens, no feedback whatsoever. Is this because it thinks this account is already "added"?

When I try Add Server, I enter my azure dev ops server name, then for user name/password I enter my MS account email and password. I leave domain empty. I get a message:
"Server already exists."

Here is what I expect to see (screenshot from VS 2017 on Windows):

[image: Screenshot of Team Explorer from VS 2017 on Windows]

Instead, nothing gets populated the way it normally does in Team Explorer: Pending changes, work items, settings - the entire panel is empty:

[image: Screenshot of Team Explorer from VS 8.0.3.14 on Mac]

I do switch between Windows and Mac a lot, but if I remember correctly, everything worked fine from both workspaces before, so it probably happened when I upgraded to Visual Studio 8.0.3.14 on my Mac. Any ideas on how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wondered the same thing but without the update process in my back pocket... meaning I haven't written any C# in a while but I'm coming back to it.  I set up a project with TFS in Azure Dev Ops on my pc, then went to check it out on my Mac and couldn't find any reference anywhere to TFS.  Subversion and Git are in there, but no TFS.  It took a little while to find it, but here's what I found.  The short answer is they want you to use Git, not TFS as TFS is not supported in VS 2019 for Mac.  The article does list work-arounds.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/mac/tf-version-control?view=vsmac-2019